# What is going on vagrant VM while kitchen converges

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

When I do a kitchen converge sometimes the logs on the console get stuck. For eg:

```
* execute[apt-get -q update] action run
  - execute apt-get -q update
```

Is there any way I can check what is going on , on the vagrant VM exactly? In this case when we do an `apt-get update` there are lots of logs displayed on the console for some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the Chef log level up to debug it will show you streaming command output, otherwise just wait and let it run.